# How to calculate cubes and functions inside AnyLogic?

Tags: java, anylogic, calculation

I have a AnyLogic simulation which is set up to use system dynamic to calculate the power of a cyclist.
For part of this I need to calculate the cube of a function and then "sin(tan^-1) of a function". Within a dynamic variable calculation I have tried this code:

cube(double Velocity)
and
sin(atan(double Gradient))

However  this is not working, any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick glance at the [help](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Ffunctions%2Fmath.html&resultof=%22%63%75%62%65%22%20) reveals the code you need. In your case:

`pow(velocity, 3)`

and

`sin(pow(tan(myValue), -1))`

Please learn to use the help first. And also add what errors/problems you hit when you tried something already :)